# The command \> is already defined?

Tags: macros

I got bored with writing `\langle` and `\rangle` in my code, so I decided to create the commands `\<` and `\>` for these. That is, I put the following in my header.

```
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}
```

This...doesn't work. It doesn't mind `\<`, but apparently `\>` is already defined. This made me interested, and I tried to find out what it does, if it does anything. But I cannot find anything about this command.

Note that I can override this by just going

```
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}
```

but, well, it feels dirty redefining an existing command!

Therefore, my question is,

What does `\>` do? Does it do anything? Does it matter that I am reassigning it?

(On a side note, why can I type `\<` here, but typing `\<` without the space gives > ?)

Comment: `\>` is used in the `tabbing` environment.  if you never use `tabbing`, you are probably okay. regarding `\<`, this is sometimes used (as `\< ... >` ) to indicate metacode; how it's defined in what you're doing depends on the document class and packages being used.

Comment: From `texdef`I got `\>: macro:->\mskip \medmuskip`
`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Okay, I haven't come across tabbing before. However, it seems that \< is a command in tabbing. Why can I assign this but not \>?

Comment: Re your side note: not sure, but you can use backticks (`\``) to highlight inline code, to avoid the issue.

Comment: Does your editor have the auto completion tool? It is easy nowadays to use extensible commands with editor's tools. Also, if you really want the symbol `<` (and not the `\langle`) (some people think that they are the same) you just type it directly on keyboard.

Comment: @Sigur ...but they are not the same...

Comment: @user1729 -- in `latex.ltx`, `\>` is actually defined (with `\def`); `\<` is only `\let` to a particular meaning.  i'd have to do some more exploring/testing to figure out if this is what makes the difference, but it's a place to start.

Comment: @user1729, you're right. I only asked to be sure that you're wishing that symbol and not the simple `>`. Well, why not define `\lb` and `\rb`. Then you don't need to press `shift` to type `\>`.

Comment: @Sigur You still need two keystrokes! Plus, `\<' and `\>' have the added advantage of making the raw code more readable. (Also, I should say that my motivation behind asking this question was simply curiosity, rather than having a problem I needed to overcome.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton tabbing commands only get their definition locally within that environment. `\>` is a math space

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `\<` and `\>` are being used as part of the `tabbing` environment syntax. Their meaning is defined inside this environment via `\let` so LaTeX doesn't really care about whether or not they are defined outside and how.

Thus a redefinition of `\<`  and a definition of `\>`on top-level is fine and even `tabbing` could still be used as long as you are prepared to use `\langle` and `\rangle` in there and not your abbrevs for it as those get redefined locally.

So could a (re)definition of those commands backfire?

Yes it could in two scenarios:

1. If you incorporate math formulas from other authors (for some reason) and they used `\>` for math spacing corrections
2. If you used some class or package that internally used `tabbing`, say to format a title page and you place one of your formulas in there

Neither is really a very realistic case, so in reality you should be fine.

Now why is `\>` defined? If you look into the LaTeX manual this command is not listed, instead `\:` is offered for the "medium math space" (page 51 Lamport). However in plain TeX Don Knuth used `\>` for this. Now as far as "fine points of math typesetting is concerned, LaTeX really just follows plain in nearly all cases (plus adding the additional amstex environments etc) so `\>`is kept available (outside `tabbing` for all those people who are used to Don's conventions.