# Renew command \> to \rangle

Tags: macros

I would like to use the following commands (in order to simplify writing):

```
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}
```

Would there be any dangerous consequences of this? I know that by default `\>` inserts `\medmuskip`, but I am not using this command.

Comment: It is possible that you use this command *indirectly* without being aware of it, via some package or other.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what worries me. Any suggestions on how to keep the things safe are welcome!

Comment: Redefining `\>` and `\<` might cause havoc if you need to use the `tabbing` environment.

Comment: @Mico More precisely, using `$\<a\>$` in a tabbing environment would cause havoc. If this is needed, it's sufficient to use `\langle` and `\rangle` in the special situation. Nothing would happen otherwise.

Comment: Subset of [macros - The command \> is already defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126084/the-command-is-already-defined) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You risk that some obscure package defines something in term of `\>` or define `\<` and `\>` themselves.

A quick search reveals that `\<` is defined in

```
amsdtx.cls
amsldoc.cls
circ.sty
cjhebrew.sty
gmmeta.sty
greektonoi.sty
jlreq.cls
lhcyralt.sty
lhcyrkoi.sty
lhcyrwin.sty
pax.sty
AlProTex.sty
dev209.sty
```

The command `\>` is redefined in

```
bxcjkjatype.sty
gn-logic14.sty
greektonoi.sty
lhcyralt.sty
lhcyrkoi.sty
lhcyrwin.sty
pax.sty
AlProTex.sty
sgamevar.sty
zxjatype.sty
```

I can't exclude there are other instances where different ways of defining commands are used.

I'd not do it anyway, even if it's not that risky. Better do

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiters{\foo}{\langle}{\rangle}
```

(choose a meaningful name for your application) and use

```
\foo{x} \foo[\big]{x} \foo[\Big]{x} \foo[\bigg]{x} \foo[\Bigg]{x} \foo*{x}
```

for choosing the size of the delimiters (the last one is for automatic sizing with `\left` and `\right`, use it carefully).

If you decide to use `\<` and `\>` beware that inside a `tabbing` environment you will have to use `\langle` and `\rangle` because `tabbing` redefines the two commands for its own purposes (but just inside the environment).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I think I will use `\DeclarePairedDelimiters`, thanks for pointing out this interesting command.